# d3 d3-timeline plugin date format

Tags: c#, d3.js, timestamp

Im returning a timestamp from c# but I can't figure out what format this plugin is using. I've tried ticks but the number seems to be way off.

So their testData looks like

```
var testData = [
 {label: "person a", times: [
      {"starting_time": 1355752800000, "ending_time": 1355759900000},
      {"starting_time": 1355767900000, "ending_time": 1355774400000}]},
 {label: "person b", times: [
      {"starting_time": 1355759910000, "ending_time": 1355761900000}]},
  {label: "person c", times: [
      {"starting_time": 1355761910000, "ending_time": 1355763910000}]},
  ];
```

I tried Ticks but this is the result

```
    string time = person.SomeTimeStamp.Ticks.ToString()
    // returns 635584863542470000
```

So to compare the two...

```
135575280000
635584863542470000
```

Sorry I just don't recognize this time format and d3 is a little new to me and I don't see it referenced in the plugin documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date format used there are milliseconds since epoch (January 1st 1970). You can get that by multiplying the UNIX timestamp by 1000.